# Grails 3 - Angular template asset pipeline not bundling converted js files into application.js

Tags: gradle, asset-pipeline, assets, angular-template, grails3

I'm using Grails 3.1.10, angular-template-asset-pipeline 2.2.6, and asset-pipeline-gradle 2.8.2

It's tough for me to share config files as I work behind a firewall but the general issue is mostly similar to this https://github.com/bertramdev/grails-asset-pipeline/issues/336  (discussion started so i'll have to update question as things go)

Everything works fine under 'grails run-app' but when i run 'grails war':

1. the templates get correctly converted to js files
2. are exploded in tomcat under /webapps/myApp/assets
3. are **not** present in the application.js bundled result, therefore my app cannot find any html.

Any help appreciated.

I was required to put assets stuff in my application.groovy development environment for run-app to work, but i'm not sure if application.groovy is used when running 'grails war' .. i'm not a fan of having duplicate asset pipeline configurations. (build.gradle as well as application.groovy for each environment)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After i figured out which config file the configuraitons where coming from (run-app -> application.groovy, grails war -> build.gradle) ... i figured it out.

I got it to work with the following steps...

1. I moved all my templateUrl: 'file.html' calls to templateUrl: '/myApp/file.html' (directives and view code)
2. i set my "includePathInName= true"
3. i put my .tpl.html files in grails-app/assets/javascripts/myApp/templates

**Important takeaway here is that grails-app/assets/javascripts/templates would not work for me.**